# glReadPixels returns wrong values

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, endianness, glreadpixels

I try to get rendered pixels color.

```
gl.glColor3f(1f, 0, 0);
//draw
gl.glReadPixels(lastX - pw / 2, MyCanvas.this.getHeight()
            - (lastY - ph / 2), pw, ph, GL.GL_RED, GL.GL_FLOAT,
            pixelBuffer);
float r, g, b;
r = pixelBuffer.getFloat();
g = pixelBuffer.getFloat();
b =pixelBuffer.getFloat();
pixelBuffer.rewind();
System.out.println(r+" "+g+" "+b);
```

there is real pure red color on the screen, but glReadPixels returns to the r very strange value 4.6006E-41, why???

Comment: Are you sure you can get red, green, and blue out after you passed in `GL.GL_RED`?

Comment: Buffer actually can hold all three values, but only red is stored, other g and b is zeroed

Comment: That's not what the documentation says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`glReadPixels` documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) says:

> Storage parameters set by glPixelStore, such as GL_PACK_LSB_FIRST and GL_PACK_SWAP_BYTES, affect the way that data is written into memory.

So check your `glPixelStore` configuration.  To wit, your byte order is backward.

```
0x0000803F => 4.600602988224807e-41
0x3F800000 => 1.0
```

Useful links:

- http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html
- http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html

Answer (score 0):

Use GL_RGB instead of GL_RED as format.